# Generating random values in static methods seem to cache

Tags: c#

I have a static method in a static class which can generate random strings, like this:

```
public static class DataGenerator
    {
        public static string GenerateRandomString(int length)
        {
            const string Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            var random = new Random();
            return new string(
                Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, length)
                    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                    .ToArray());
        }
}
```

When I call this method multiple times from the same calling function, it seems to cache the generated string.

Here is an example of usage:

```
var item = new CodeDescActivePo()
                {
                    Active = true, 
                    Code = DataGenerator.GenerateRandomString(10), 
                    Description = DataGenerator.GenerateRandomString(10)
                };
```

Notice that there are 2 calls to GenerateRandomString, I would expect 2 unique random numbers, in this case Code and Description are always the same.

Why would GenerateRandomString not generate a fresh random number each time?

Comment: Random is created with the same seed?

Comment: var random = new Random(); is wrong. You should initialize only once, then use it forever. If you new it every time, it could generate same values.

Comment: I don't know who voted to reopen, but if you want a static-specific duplicate see [Random number generator only generating one random number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number). This question is not unique.

Comment: Even if there was no static-specific answer, this would still be a duplicate. The two issues are fundamentally the same, and the answer applies to both.

Comment: Just an observation. If you want random strings have you considered Membership.GeneratePassword, Path.GetRandomFileName. Although maybe that's a bit hacky.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling `var random = new Random();` too quickly together. Since the default seed is time based, the seed is the same. Better to create this variable once and `Random.Next()` every time you need it.

```
public static class DataGenerator
{
    private readonly static Random random = new Random();

    public static string GenerateRandomString(int length)
    {
       //etc etc using random.Next()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a `new Random()` instance for each call. By default it is seeded with the current system time, which means that multiple `Random` instances created at the same time will give the same values.

Make the `Random` instance a `static` field instead to keep it alive between the calls.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers.

**Solution:** Again from MSDN

> This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then explicitly providing this new seed value to the Random(Int32) constructor. For more information, see the Random(Int32) constructor.

Comment: The example they give uses `Thread.Sleep` to demonstrate how the default constructor works. In actually code, this is not one of the few legitimate uses of `Thread.Sleep` and should be avoided.

Comment: @NathanCooper: That's why I have provided another solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my comment, I'm glad you agree. I just wanted to make sure the OP didn't get the wrong idea.