# C# Returning A Random String From A List

Tags: c#, random

I wrote out a list filled with answers for a question. I want to use my GetAnswer() method to return the current answer as a string.

The issue that I'm having is that I can't get the random answer that I selected to print out.

```
namespace Magic8Ball_Logic
{

public class Magic8Ball
{
    private List<string> _answers;
    private int _currentIndex;
    public Magic8Ball()
    {
        _answers = new List<string>();
        _answers.Add("It is certain.");
        _answers.Add("It is decidedly so.");
        _answers.Add("Without a doubt.");
    }

    public Magic8Ball(List<string> answers)
    {
        //I won't use the default. Use the ones passed in.
        _answers = answers;
    }

    public void Shake()
    {
        //picking the index of the answer to show the user
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.Next(_answers.Count);
        string randomString = _answers[index];
    }

    public string GetAnswer()
    {
        //using the index picked by shake to return the answer
        return randomString;
    }
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: Remove your `GetAnswer` method and let `Shake` return `_answers[index]` or in `Shake` save the index as a class variable and `GetAnswer` will return `_answers[_index]`

Comment: The `randomString` is a local variable to the `Shake` method. It isn’t accessible from outside. Move it to the class fields

Comment: Btw. Depending on how often you "Shake", once you fix this you may find that [creating a Random object each time isn't helping you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24753931/1734730).

Answer (score 1):

Tell me,if you don't understand something.

```
   public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _answers.Add("It is certain.");
        _answers.Add("It is decidedly so.");
        _answers.Add("Without a doubt.");
    }

    List<string> _answers = new List<string>();

    private void BtnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetAnswer());

    }
    string GetAnswer()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i = 0;
        int _rnd = rnd.Next(_answers.Count);
        foreach (string answer in _answers)
        {
            if (i == _rnd)
            {
                return answer;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code:

```
public void Shake()
{
    //picking the index of the answer to show the user
    Random r = new Random();
    _currentIndex = r.Next(_answers.Count);
}

public string GetAnswer()
{
    //using the index picked by shake to return the answer
    return _answers[_currentIndex];
}
```

You might need to make your Random `static`. There are other threads that you can refer to for this.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by using the Random class that comes with the system.
Make sure you have `using System;` at the top of your code. If you want to avoid adding this line at the top of your code, you can just add `System.` before every time you see the word "Random".

```
Random rnd = new Random();
return _asnswers[rnd.Next(0, _answers.Count);
```

By the way, try to avoid using variables with '_' at the beginning because it is used for variables from another type, such as:

```
using _StartWith = System.File;
```

Name the variables "answers" (preferred) or "Answers".
The code will work 100% but this is just for when other people look at your code they will know what variable is what type.

Also, I assume you want to shuffle the answers so I will help you with it too:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = _answers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i++)
{
    _answers.Add(    // Add the random removed answer
    _answers.Remove( // Removes the random answer
    rnd.Next(0, i)));// Randomizes a random answer in a range of 0 to the number of answers that didn't get picked before.
}
```

Good luck!
Tell me if I helped :)

Comment: Look more closely at the provided code. This is not a solution to the problem.